# In development, how to listen to laptop keystrokes in react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I am looking to trigger functions from within a RN app, for example logging out without clicking a button in the app. It's for testing/development. Is there a way to send a message to the app from my laptop keyboard to the app in development? Note I am not trying to do it from the keyboard on the Android/iOS device, but instead from my laptop when running the simulator/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm).

Vysor lets you view and control your Android on your computer. So, you can type on PC keyboard, the Vysor will send to Android, acting as a Physical Keyboard.

It currently works on Android.

Comment: I think the only way is using a bluetooth keyboard in iOS. But it won't work on emulator.